# Determine if all erlang processes spawned are idle

Tags: erlang

I want to know if all my spawned processes are at idle or not doing anything. So I have this particular example that spawns 1000 erlang processes of `proc/3`

```
proc(A,B,C) ->
    receive
        {do} ->
            NewA = % doing something
            NewB = % doing something
            NewC = % doing something
            % doing something
            % ...
            io:format("Process: ~w is done doing something.", [self()]),
            proc(NewA,NewB,NewC)
    end
```

[<0.33.0>,<0.34.0>,<0.35.0>,<0.36.0>...<0.1032.0>]

Now each of these processes receives a message `{do}` telling them to execute the statements under it concurrently with the other processes. How will I know if all the process are done executing or simply they are now in idle?

Comment: can you just end a process when it finishes its work and becomes idle? if you can, you can use a monitor for instance.

Comment: No, the processes must remain alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem, I solved it by sending back a message back to the process who is responsible to send the do message. In my case I had only to count the number of answers.

```
proc(A,B,C,From) ->
    receive
        {do} ->
            NewA = % doing something
            NewB = % doing something
            NewC = % doing something
            % doing something
            % ...
            io:format("Process: ~w is done doing something.", [self()]),
            From ! {job_done,self()},
            proc(NewA,NewB,NewC,From)
    end
```